# What are the actual precise rules for how log4j reads config setting names?

Tags: java, log4j

I found our log4j config was inconsistently using uppercase or lowercase letters for starting options. When I tried to make them consistent, I found that sometimes it wouldn't let me use the case I wanted to use.

So of course I went to the documentation, which says:

> ... any setter method in FooBarAppender corresponds to a configurable
>   option. For example, in RollingFileAppender the setMaxBackupIndex(int
>   maxBackups) method corresponds to the maxBackupIndex option. The first
>   letter of the option can be upper case, i.e. MaxBackupIndex and
>   maxBackupIndex are equivalent but not MAXBACKUPIndex nor
>   mAXBackupIndex.

But sometimes this paragraph is a lie. For example, this is OK:

```
log4j.appender.MY_LOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
```

But this is *not* OK:

```
log4j.appender.MY_LOG.Layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
```

My question is, what is the complete list of specific situations for which this paragraph in their docs is a lie, or alternatively, how can I figure out which style I have to use without reading the log4j source code?

Comment: *"how can I figure out which style I have to use"* Look at the examples.

Comment: Cargo cult programming for the win. :(